# Send a twiter message from the terminal

Tags: bash, twitter, virtual-terminal

Is there away to send a message form the terminal or write a shell bash file that fill send a message to twiter.

Comment: you can look a guide here: http://xmodulo.com/access-twitter-command-line-linux.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I the end I started to use the t application I think it is written in ruby but it is very Easy to use once set up.

Answer (score 1):

Not a one-line answer, but you can use `curl` and [the Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) to build a request and post a tweet. Requires some reading though!